# Limit azure pipeline to only run one after the other rather than in parallel

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set up a PR Pipeline in Azure. As part of this pipeline I run a number of regression tests. These run against a regression test database - we have to clear out the database at the start of the tests so we are certain what data is in there and what should come out of it.

This is all working fine until the pipeline runs multiple times in parallel - then the regression database is being written to multiple times and the data returned from it is not what is expected.

How can I stop a pipeline running in parallel - I've tried Google but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

If the pipeline is running, the the next build should wait (not for all pipelines - I want to set it on a single pipeline), is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your exact use case, you may be able to control this with the right trigger configuration.

In my case, I had a pipeline scheduled to kick off every time a Pull Request is merged to the main branch in Azure. The pipeline deployed the code to a server and kicked off a suite of tests. Sometimes, when two merges occurred just minutes apart, the builds would fail due to a shared resource that required synchronisation being used.

I fixed it by [Batching CI Runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs)

I changed my basic config

```
trigger:
  - main
```

to use the more verbose syntax allowing me to turn batching on

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main
```

With this in place, a new build will only be triggered for `main` once the previous one has finished, no matter how many commits are added to the branch in the meantime.

That way, I avoid having too many builds being kicked off and I can still use multiple agents where needed.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation to the OP, and `batch: true` doesn't help me, because as the documentation of it says, it only batches things up for the same branch (as has been made clear on this answer). So for two quick pushes for the same branch, the second would wait for the first. However, if you start preparing the PR for when a running pipeline completes, it kicks off another one, because the PR's pipeline occurs on a different branch (e.g. "refs/pull/1546/merge") than the push, so they end up running in parallel and conflicting. Would be nice if there was a proper 'mutex' for the build.

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this is to model your test regression database as an "environment" in your pipeline, then use the "[Exclusive Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update#exclusive-deployment-lock-policy)" check to prevent concurrent "deployment" to that "environment".

Unfortunately this approach comes with several disadvantages inherent to "environments" in YAML pipelines:

- you must set up the check manually in the UI, it's not controlled in source code.
- it will only prevent that particular deployment job from running concurrently, not an entire pipeline.
- the fake "environment" you create will appear in alongside all other environments, cluttering the environment view if you happen to use environments for "real" deployments. This is made worse by this view being a big sack of all environments, there's no grouping or hierarchy.

Overall the initial YAML reimplementation of Azure Pipelines mostly ignored the concepts of releases, deployments, environments. A few piecemeal and low-effort aspects have subsequently been patched in, but without any real overarching design or apparent plan to get to parity with the old release pipelines.

Comment: Alternatively it's possible to apply an "Exclusive Lock" on a dummy "variable group" instead of "environment". It allowed me to achieve the same effect with less environment-related side effects.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "[Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline)" extension by Maik van der Gaag.

It needs to add to you DevOps and configure end of the main pipeline and point to your test pipeline.

Can find more details on Maik's [blog](https://msftplayground.com/2019/02/trigger-a-pipeline-from-an-azure-devops-pipeline/).

Answer (score -2):

According to your description, you could use your own self-host agent. 
Simply [**deploy your own self-hosted agents**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install).

Just need to make sure your self host agent environment is the same as your local development environment.

Under this situation, since your agent pool only have one available build agent. When multiple builds triggered, only one build will be running simultaneously.  Others will stay in queue with a specific order for agents. Unless the prior build finished, it will not run with next build.

For other pipeline, just need to keep use the host agent pool.

Comment: This can't have been a serious suggestion - going to all the effort of standing up self hosted agent infrastructure that's limited to a single agent, just to control concurrent executions of a one pipeline?

Comment: I think it is a serious suggestion; because other pipelines could still use other pools with multiple agents.

Comment: It actually does not even work. If your pipeline is made up of multiple jobs, a local agent will mix the jobs of the runs...